# Lodash omit not working after angular migration to 6

Tags: angular, lodash, angular6

I've this function working fine:

```
 SFcopy = _.omit(SFcopy, (objectValue: any, objectField: string): boolean => {
            return (
                !defaultSF.hasOwnProperty(objectField) ||
                _.isEqual(defaultSF[objectField], objectValue)
            );
         });
```

but when I updated angular to 6 the function stopped working and it shows me the following error that I do not know how to fix

> ERROR in src/app/shared/search-filter.ts(1156,33): error TS2345:
>   Argument of type '(objectValue: any, objectField: string) => boolean'
>   is not assignable to parameter of type 'Many'.   Type
>   '(objectValue: any, objectField: string) => boolean' is not assignable
>   to type 'PropertyKey[]'.
>       Property 'includes' is missing in type '(objectValue: any, objectField: string) => boolean'.

[image]

LODASH version(update to the last version doesn't work):

```
"lodash": "^4.17.4",
"@types/lodash": "^4.14.62",
```

Can you help me to fix it?

Thank you.

Comment: i think it is bcoz objectValue has a type any change it to boolean it may work

Comment: or remove the   boolean from here _.omit(SFcopy, (objectValue: any, objectField: string)

Comment: I tried both, but it does not work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`_.omit`](https://lodash.com/docs/3.10.1#omit) was changed in Lodash 4. Now the predicate version is extracted and renamed to [`_.omitBy`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#omitBy). Change it to [`_.omitBy`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#omitBy) and it should work as before.